# Deploying a java JNI (contains C++ code) application on eclipse

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to develop keylogger application that contains a mix of `Java` and `C++` code. But I don't know how to deploy it in `Eclipse IDE`. Where I have to put the `.dll`, `.lib` and `C++` files inside the `Java` project.

Answer (score 4):

1. Build your java interface in eclipse. (myInterface.java)
2. call:  javah -jni com.mypackage.myInterface

   A com_mypackage_myInterface.h will be built for you in your classes
   folder.
3. Move the com_mypackage_myInterface.h into your c++ project and
   use that to code your c++ implementation. Do not change anything in
   your .h file
4. Compile your c++ project so a dll (or .so) file is
   generated
5. Copy the dll back into your Java project (lib or
   WEB-INF/lib folder).
6. Have a static call to load your dll ...

   static {
       System.loadLibrary("MYINTERFACE");// DLL created 
    }